# Can I capture lambda variables without std::function?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17

Is it possible to get the captured values of a lambda without using `std::function`?  I'm asking because I want to place the captured copies into my own memory, which `std::function` cannot do as they don't support custom allocators.

(I assume allocator support missing for `std::function` is due to a very good reason, perhaps the logic behind capturing values in a lambda is extremely difficult to implement?  But if it's possible, I'd like to try it myself.)

Background:  I'm asking to learn more about lambda in C++.  I'd like to place the captured values and reference pointers in over-aligned memory for a thread pool system I'm writing as an academic exercise.  I also really like the brevity writing lambdas with automatic captures, it'd make for a very easy "job" writing interface I think.

```
class MyFunction {
public:

    // I want more than just the function pointer, 
    // I also want the captured value copies or references too
    // I'm unsure how to really accomplish this though.
    MyFunction & operator=( ??? ) {
        ???
    }

};

int main(){
    int captureThis = 1;
    MyFunction func = [=]()->void {
        printf("%i", captureThis);
    };
}
```

Comment: What are you really trying to do?  That is, if you could obtain the references to the captured values, what you would do with it?

Comment: Note that when you define an initialize an object, it's using a *constructor* not assignment.

Comment: you do not need to use a lambda expression. You can write your own custom functor that stores the captures wherever you like

Comment: Also note that there are no lambda "types". All lambdas are have a unique type (class), even two that are otherwise exactly character by character the same will have different types.

Comment: @selbie - writing a thread pool system, for learning purposes.  The goal is to place this data in over-aligned memory, but I also want to use this as an excuse to learn.

Comment: [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? I mean not that you need to have captures of a lambda in your own memory, but the problem to which you think that would be the solution?

Comment: oh, ninja'd ;), You should put that information in the question. "why" is always good info. Sometimes it is necessary for an answer and if not its still helpful

Comment: @AnneQuinn - it sounds interesting, but I'm not sure why that would be a requirement of implementing a worker thread pool. (Having done one myself with lambdas, it never occurred to me that I might want to optimize the memory alignment). Can you elaborate?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number - understood, I'll add that to the question, sorry for the trouble.  Also, functors are definitely more flexible, but I really do enjoy the brevity that lambda allow.

Comment: I don't see why a custom allocator wouldn't work.

Comment: @selbie - Avoiding "false sharing" hasn't proven very effective in my profiling, but it did help a lot to batch all my job allocations and deallocations to occur in big chunks.  So I guess it's more about "paging" (not sure if that's the right word) than alignment

Comment: `allocator` was introduced in '90s to address far and near addresses which this days hardware had. Now `allocator` is used for different purposes. So when `std::function` was introduced near and far addresses are not longer in use (old hardware do not use moder compilers) and nobody though that alternative usages of it are needed.

Comment: *"Is it possible to get the captured values of a lambda without using `std::function`?"* captured values are inaccessible outside of the lambda, std::function cannot access neither. We can move the (whole) lambda in any place though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking values of captured variables outside of lambda would not look good but at least you can use a factory function to produce it with its unique "lambda" template type (also with help of auto on the final type) so that you can do extra work between what thread calls and what you initialize:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

template <typename F>
struct Callable
{
    Callable(const F && lambda):func(std::move(lambda))
    {
        
    }

    // this is what the std::thread calls
    void operator()()
    {
        // you can check the captured variable
        int out;
        func(out,false);
        std::cout<< "Callable successfully found out the value of captured variable: "<<out <<std::endl;
        func(out,true);
    }
    const F func;
};


template<typename F>
Callable<F> CallableFactory(F&& lambda)
{
    return Callable<F>(std::forward<F>(lambda)); // or std::move(lambda)
}

int main()
{
    // variable to capture
    int a=1;
    
    auto callable = CallableFactory([&](int & outputCapturedValue, bool runNow){
        // not looking good as its not possible from outside (because they are private variables & depends on implementation of C++)
        // if checking the captured variables
        if(!runNow)
        {
            outputCapturedValue = a;
            std::cout << "inside the lambda: a=" << a <<std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout<<"algorithm runs"<<std::endl;
        }
    });
    
    
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    threads.emplace_back(std::move(callable));
    threads[0].join();
    
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
inside the lambda: a=1
Callable successfully found out the value of captured variable: 1
algorithm runs
```

---

If its only for having an array of lambdas processed by array of threads, you can use smart-pointers and an extra container struct to box/unbox them during work-distribution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>


struct ICallable
{
    virtual void operator()()=0;
};

template <typename F>
struct Callable:public ICallable
{
    Callable(const F && lambda):func(std::move(lambda))
    {
        
    }

    // this is what the std::thread calls
    void operator()() override
    {
        func();
    }
    const F func;
};


template<typename F>
std::shared_ptr<ICallable> CallablePtrFactory(F&& lambda)
{
    return std::shared_ptr<ICallable>(new Callable<F>(std::forward<F>(lambda)));
}

struct CallableContainer
{
    std::shared_ptr<ICallable> callable;
    void operator()()
    {
        callable.get()->operator()();
    }        
};

int main()
{
    // variable to capture
    int a=1;

    // simulating work pool
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<ICallable>> callables;
    callables.push_back(CallablePtrFactory([&](){
        std::cout<< "a="<<a<<std::endl;
    }));

    // simulating worker pool load-balancing
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    threads.emplace_back(CallableContainer{ callables[0] });
    threads[0].join();
    
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
a=1
```

---

If you're after a custom-allocation for the container, you can just use a second parameter for the factory function. Following example uses placement-new on a stack buffer. But still the lambda itself has something else outside of it making container's size not changed by its lambda (just like a function-pointer):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>


struct ICallable
{
    virtual void operator()()=0;
};

template <typename F>
struct Callable:public ICallable
{
    Callable(const F && lambda):func(std::move(lambda))
    {
        currentSize = sizeof(*this); std::cout<<"current size = "<<currentSize <<" (useful for alignement of next element?)" <<std::endl;
    }

    // this is what the std::thread calls
    void operator()() override
    {
        func();
    }
    int currentSize;
    const F func;
    
};


template<typename F>
std::shared_ptr<ICallable> CallablePtrFactory(F&& lambda, char * buffer)
{
    return std::shared_ptr<ICallable>(
                new (buffer) Callable<F>(std::forward<F>(lambda)),
                [](ICallable *){ /* placement-new does not require a delete! */}
                );
}

struct CallableContainer
{
    std::shared_ptr<ICallable> callable;
    void operator()()
    {
        callable.get()->operator()();
    }        
};

int main()
{
    // variable to capture
    int a=1;

    char buffer[10000];

    // simulating work pool
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<ICallable>> callables;
    
    
    callables.push_back(
        // observe the buffer for placement-new
        CallablePtrFactory([&](){
            std::cout<< "a="<<a<<std::endl;
        },buffer /* you should compute offset for next element */)
    );

  

    // simulating worker pool load-balancing
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    threads.emplace_back(CallableContainer{ callables[0] });
    threads[0].join();
    
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
current size = 24 (useful for alignement of next element?)
a=1
```

Comment: (Can we start calling these things 'Callables' or something, and give the word Functor back to the functional programming world? cf. https://isocpp.org/blog/2017/02/cppchat10-the-great-functor-debate / https://youtu.be/be4sRg9iO-A?t=1320)

Comment: Maybe also a ```std::vector``` of ```std::shared_ptr``` of ```std::any``` works, but if threads can take any function without changing their types, these callables are just mid-layer between threads and the scope of theirs.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I added a placement-new version at last part using a stack-buffer (I did not check any error against alignment etc). This looks a bit better maybe? I guess memory pools would work with static buffers like that, with just moving objects around.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat but changing interior of lambda still doesn't change the total size of container of it. Because its data is somewhere else. Which I don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: Just a side note: I do not really see why we would want to share the pointers over different owners, actually the thread pool class should be the unique owner, so a `std::unique_ptr` might be the more appropriate choice.

Comment: @Aconcagua if user needs a parallel-for implementation, then multiple instances of same lambda would be run. At least it would also work when not in thread-pool scope. Otherwise thread-pool would be have to be coupled with work-pool to not destructed while under computations.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik Not really sure what image you have in mind. Usually one thread from the pool would execute one runner, and unless you detach the threads we would need to `join` at some point of time. Parallel for should be able to operate on the same data in general, but appears problematic to me in respect to adding and removing runners dynamically, though would need to inspect yet a bit deeper.

Comment: @Aconcagua For example, OpenMP's parallel-for runs same code block just with different interator value. The iterator value could just be the thread's id value and they all would run it until all complete, if number of threads less than iterations, then it could be better with a queue system with just 1 element broadcasted to all threads or N copies stolen by faster threads. I guess a queue with "faster thread steals the work" would be better.  Or just copy same lambda to all, then use an atomic counter by threads to reach target value. A lambda may not capture the iteration from client side.

Comment: Still no need for the shared pointer. Each of the parallel loop runs would require to run its own runner, and that could be retrieved from one and the same vector of unique_ptrs. The more interesting part is how would these parallel loop runs react if no runner is available? How to synchronise correctly adding new runners? How to extend the number of threads in use (if I recall correclty it's not possible at all with OpenMP, but I might err...). In any case it doesn't look too natural to me.

Comment: Probably simpler is an approach where you create some N threads in advance and each thread looks at some runner queue; if there's an element it executes it, otherwise waits on a `std::condition_variable`; on adding new runners `notify_one` would wake up a thread that could then grab the new runner.

Comment: My usage matches what @Aconcagua describes, with the program hitting a fence every frame where all jobs must finish.  After that, the memory they used can safely be released at once.  It's part of why I really want to control the allocation of lambda 'jobs', so I can pool the memory and do that.  (I also do the approach of keeping n threads alive and waiting on a condvar to check a queue)

Comment: @AnneQuinn yes it would be much faster to wait on a queue to get the lambda rather than directly starting a new thread with lambda. I kept simplicity there.

Comment: sorry for the extra comment, but thank you for showing me how to perform the type erasure/preservation too; I don't use inheritance very often, so I was pursuing some very cursed dead-ends with method pointer punning, before seeing the light

Answer (score 1):

Considering the thread pool system you mention in comments then you could try a polymorphic approach:

```
class ThreadRoutine
{
protected:
    virtual ~ThreadRoutine() { }
public:
    virtual void run() = 0;
};

template <typename Runner>
class ThreadRoutineT
{
    // variant 1:
    Runner m_runner; // store by value;
    // variant 2:
    std::reference_wrapper<Runner> m_runner;
public:
    void run() override { m_runner(); } // call operator()
};
```

Now you might store your thread routines in a `std::vector` (note: pointers to, by value would lead to object slicing; likely `std::unique_ptr`, possibly, depending on use case, a classic raw pointer might fit, too).

You could even implement *both* variants, your thread pool manager could provide an additional parameter in the thread creation function or maybe even more elegant distinguish by overloading that function (l-value reference: create the reference wrapper variant; r-value reference: create the value variant, move-construct it), e.g. like:

```
class ThreadManager
{
    template <typename Runner>
    void createThread(Runner& runner)
    {
        // assuming std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ThreadRoutine>>
        m_runners.emplace_back
        (
            // assuming appropriate constructor
            std::make_unique<ThreadRoutineRef>(runner)
        );
        // return some kind of thread handle or start thread directly?
        // thread handle: could be an iterator into a std::list
        // (instead of std::vector) as these iterators do not invalidate
        // if elements preceding in the list are removed
        // alternatively an id as key into a std::[unordered_]map
    }
    template <typename Runner>
    void createThread(Runner&& runner)
    {
        m_runners.emplace_back
        (
            // assuming appropriate constructor
            std::make_unique<ThreadRoutineVal>(std::move(runner))
        );
    }
}
```

About the alignment issue: The specific template instantiations would select the alignment appropriate for the template argument type, so you wouldn't have to consider anything particular.